# Android and Kernel-Modules

Tags: android, linux, kernel-module

So - Android is build on top of a stripped down linux system. Most of the convenient utilities are missing but all the basics are there.

I can call insmod and rmmod. No problem.

But where do kernel-modules and firmware files reside? I can't find any. there is no /lib/modules in the standard distribution.

Problem: I need modules. For sure don't want to compile support for each and every usb-device in the world into the linux-kernel. Where should I put them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules should be stored in `/system/lib/modules`, or at least that seems the general consensus in most ROMs.